# Determining MS Project Task Lineage

Tags: c#, office-interop, ms-project

I have a MS Project file which I am using the Primary Interop Assemblies to parse. How can I determine the lineage of a task? I was relying on the WBS code, however the client has started to fiddle with this field and it no longer represents the hierarchy of the data.

Edit: By lineage I mean a way to identify where in the hierarchy the task exists. By default the WBS code mimics this perfectly.

I need this information to determine what is the parent for a task.

Example

- A
- B

  - B1
  - B2
  - B3
- C

The Lineage for B3 would be 2.3 (If we counted by 1, like project)

Comment: By lineage are you referring to its predecessors and successors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Task object's OutlineNumber property and the PredecessorTasks collection.

HTM

Colby Africa

Answer (score 0):

Use 'OutlineChildren' property:

```
// from caller:
ListTasks(prj.OutlineChildren, "");

void ListTasks(Tasks lst, string indent)
{
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task t in lst) {
        Log(indent + t.Start + " - " + t.Name);
        ListTasks(t.OutlineChildren, indent + "    ");
    }
}
```

It creates indented tree of tasks.